# Azure AD B2C add generic oauth identity provider

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a User flow in Azure AD B2C and want to configure a generic OAuth identity provider.
The MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider) seems to suggest that it is possible, but there are no specific examples and appears that I can only add an Open ID Connect provider.

Does anyone know how I can use a generic 3rd party oauth identity provider in Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/oauth2-technical-profile).

The key is:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
  <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Open ID Connect is a wrapper around Oauth, so you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

[Set up sign-up and sign-in with generic OpenID Connect using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect?pivots=b2c-user-flow)